# How do I Combine two ReduceByKey Commands for single result set

Tags: scala, count, apache-spark, cassandra

I have the following two reducByKey commands:

```
sc.cassandraTable("Data","Value")
.where("\"Time_Key\" = 100")
.select("Power")
.as( (power:Float) => (power,1))
.reduceByKey(_ + _)
.collect
```

Which outputs data like:

```
(-100,2)
(-101,5)
(-103,3)
```

and another for another column

```
sc.cassandraTable("Data","Value")
.where("\"Time_Key\" = 100")
.select("Start_Frequency")
.as( (frequency:Double) => (frequency,1))
.reduceByKey(_ + _)
.collect
```

which outputs the following numbers that are of the type Double:

```
(1.00E8,1)
(1.10E8,1)
(1.09E8,2)
```

I would like to combine these into one statement that would output both in a single command but do not know how to accomplish this.  How would I combine these two into a single statement to have a result of:

```
(-100,2)(1.00E8,1)
(-101,5)(1.10E8,1)
(-103,3)(1.09E8,2)
```

Comment: Perhaps you could make a simpler example showing what you want to do? I'm sure we don't need floating point numbers with a dozen digits to illustrate this question. You're close to getting the question re-opened, so it's probably worth the effort! Good luck.

Comment: Those numbers are Doubles not floats.  I can change them to 0's to make it look cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to count your records by one key (`Power`) and also by another key (`Start_Frequency`).

You have already accomplished this with two commands, but you'd like to be able to do it with one command. This is not possible. `reduceByKey` performs a *shuffle*: it distributes the records according to a key. There is no way to do this with two keys at once.

There are however related things you could do.

Maybe your data is large but the `filter` only keeps a small subset. You want to avoid executing the same `filter` twice. In this case you could do:

```
val filtered = sc.cassandraTable("Data","Value").where("\"Time_Key\" = 100")
filtered.cache()

val byPower = filtered
  .select("Power")
  .as( (power:Float) => (power,1))
  .reduceByKey(_ + _)
  .collect

val byFrequency = filtered
  .select("Start_Frequency")
  .as( (frequency:Double) => (frequency,1))
  .reduceByKey(_ + _)
  .collect
```

Or maybe you want to calculate the number of records by the combination of the two keys.

```
sc.cassandraTable("Data","Value")
  .where("\"Time_Key\" = 100")
  .select("Power", "Start_Frequency")
  .as((power:Float, frequency:Double) => ((power, frequency), 1))
  .reduceByKey(_ + _)
  .collect
```

In which case you get the counts for combinations of the two keys. E.g.:

```
((-100,1.00E8),1)
((-100,1.09E8),1)
((-101,1.00E8),1)
((-101,1.09E8),2)
((-101,1.10E8),2)
((-103,1.09E8),1)
((-103,1.10E8),2)
```